# SQL Query for listing all records where all values for one column are not in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Sorry the question is too vague. I'll Explain it here.
So I have Two tables say R and S.
There are 10 Products P1,P2...............P10 and each product can have 5 types T1,T2,T3,T4,T5.

Table R is a 2-column table which is sorted according to the products.

```
Products   Type

P1         T1
P1         T3
P1         T4
P2         T2
P2         T3
P3         T1
.          .
.          .
.          .
```

So R is a table which is sorted by products and describes what type of every product out of the five is available.
S is another table of all 5 types listed.

```
Type

T1        
T2         
T3         
T4         
T5
```

I need to find out List off all types that are not available for a particular product.

So the result should be:

```
Products   Type

    P1         T2
    P1         T5
    P2         T1
    P2         T4
    P2         T5
    .          .
    .          .
    .          .
    .          .
```

SInce P1 does not have T2 and T5 in table R, it should be included in the result.

How can I achieve this? I tried using Left Join but I am unable to figure out the correct answer.

Help will be appreciated.!!!

Comment: To start with: There should be *three* tables: products, types (your table S), and product_types (your table R). Then you'd cross join products and types to get all posssible combinations, and from these you'd remove the existing ones. Without a product table, you'd have to generate it on-the-fly, because without that table the ten products only exist in your head; it would be impossible with the two tables only to find a product lacking all types.

Answer (score 1):

You use `cross join` to generate all the rows and then filter out the ones that exist:

```
select p.product, t.type
from (select distinct product from producttypes) p cross join
     types t left join
     producttypes pt
     on pt.product = p.product and pt.type = t.type
where pt.type is null;
```

Of course, if you have a table with all products, you can use that for `p` instead of the subquery.

Comment: I have the table R in which every product out of the 10 is present , do I still need the subquery.??

Comment: @Ravikumar . . . No.  That is what the final comment means.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `CROSS JOIN` and `NOT EXISTS`

```
select DR.product, 
       S.type
from (select distinct product from R) DR 
cross join types S
where not exists (
   select 1
   from R
   where R.product = DR.product and 
         R.type = S.type
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table product(
    product_id varchar(10) not null,
    product_type varchar(10) not null
);
go

insert into product values
('P1','T1'),
('P1','T3'),
('P1','T4'),
('P2','T2'),
('P2','T3'),
('P3','T1');
go

create table productType(
    type_id varchar(10) not null,
);
go

insert into productType values
('T1'),('T2'),('T3'),('T4'),('T5'),('T6'),('T7')

select * from product
select * 
    from 
        (select distinct(product_id) from product) as a 
        cross join 
        (select distinct(type_id) from productType) as b
 except (select * from product)
```